# Organization of template classes

Tags: c++, templates, organization

I am writing a bunch of data structures and algorithms in C++ for practice (see [github](https://github.com/Magana/Data-Structures-and-Algorithms)). I am currently writing a queue backed by a singly-linked list (that I created). If I need to include my linked list header file in the queue implementation, is it best to copy the linked list header into the queue folder for use?

I think it's important to note that **all of my classes are templates**, so based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348820/3885347), I can't create a library that can be universally used.

I don't like the idea of copying the necessary header files into the directories so they work, so I'm hoping for a cleaner/better solution.

Comment: Use a relative path to include the linked list header, something like `#include "../LinkedList/LinkedList.h"`

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to have each class in a separate folder?

Comment: @PeterSW I plan on implementing a lot of stuff and the organization will be nice I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can structure your file structure such that you can use relative paths: `#include "../linked_list.h`

2) Include the path of the header while compiling: `-IPATH/TO/YOUR/FILE/FOLDER`

Both of these are viable solutions, but I suggest you go with #2 because it works better if you decide to change file structure or want to reorganize the files. #2 is more flexible.

Comment: For #2: Let's say I have a DS that uses a queue (which uses a list), would this still work? Would the path then be to the queue.h or would it have to be a path to a folder with queue.h and list.h?

Comment: @JoseMagana No, you just need to include the queue... because the queue file will take care of its own includes. The compiler will make a tree of dependencies and then go down the line as you have more includes.